# Export rigid body simulation as fbx

Tags: animation, export, rigid-body-simulation, .fbx, rigidbody

I made a Rigid body sim and baked it now I want to export it as fbx. I didn't want to place a camera and have it as a vid. I wanted to be able to view it as 3d but whenever I export it the animation is just not appearing. I set path to copy and unchecked nla strips.

Comment: AFAIK, doesn't really support deformations outside of bones and shapekeys. Use Alembic instead.

Comment: I'll try that but I hope someone finds a walk around

Comment: You can't really force a format to export a data it can't support x) Meanwhile Alembic is designed to export such things.

Comment: Your right, Can you tell me how to view alembic files. the default 3d viewer for widows doesn't open it

Comment: Use Blender or any real production tool. Windows' 3d viewer is barely a playtoy.